# Modal Body contents not showing React, no console errors either

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a form inside a modal, I was working on a button that would add an input field then the contents of the form was no longer visible and I have no console errors either, so I have no idea what I did wrong. Any help will be appreciated:

```
    import {Button, Col, Row, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
    import _ from "lodash";

    const DropdownVariableRow = ({
      variableValue,
      modalVariableValues,
      setModalVariableValues,
      id,
    }) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(variableValue);
      return (
        <Row key={id} className={"form-group"}>
          <SimpleFormText
            label={<Fragment>Value Name</Fragment>}
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
            width={{ sm: 4 }}
            formGroupWrapper={false}
          />
          <div className="col-sm-1 text-right" style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
            <Button
              bsSize={Size.SMALL}
              bsStyle={State.DANGER}
              onClick={() => removeVariable(scriptVariable)}
            >
              <Icon icon={"fas fa-times"} />
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() =>
                addVariable(value, modalVariableValues, setModalVariableValues)
              }
            >
              Add Value
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Row>
      );
    };
    
    const addVariable = (value, modalVariableValues, setModalVariableValues) => {
      setModalVariableValues(modalVariableValues.concat([value]));
    };

    export default function ScriptVariablesFields({
    model = 'script'
    }) {
const [modalVariableValues, setModalVariableValues] = useState([])
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>EDIT DROPDOWN VALUES</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        {_.map(modalVariableValues, (variableValue) => {
          return (
            <DropdownVariableRow
              key={`DropdownVariable${variableValue}`}
              variableValue={variableValue}
              modalVariableValues={modalVariableValues}
              setModalVariableValues={setModalVariableValues}
              id={`DropdownVariableRow${variableValue}id`}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Update Values</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
}
```

I'm still very new with react, so anyone who can help with debugging will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Are these from a component framework?  Where are `Modal`, `Button`, and `Row` coming from?

Comment: Where does your `Modal` component live?  And your `addVariable` function?  Right now they're disembodied code fragments, its hard to tell how this is organized

Comment: Please provide a complete code snippet of your components.

Comment: @zero298 and Seth, I imported `Modal`, `Button` and `Row` from `React`, I have updated the code to show that.

Comment: Does anything show inside your Modal.Body at all? If you add a <h1>test</h1> instead of your map, does it show?

Comment: @ThalesKenne, yes, it does when add anything static

Answer (score 0):

Unless you lost formatting when posting, your ScriptVariablesFields functions is broken and not returning any JSX. If this is the reason, it's funny that you're not getting any errors. React elements must always return JSX

It should be something like this:

```
export default function ScriptVariablesFields({model = 'script'}) {

   const [modalVariableValues, setModalVariableValues] = useState([]);

   return (
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
         <Modal.Header closeButton>
           <Modal.Title>EDIT DROPDOWN VALUES</Modal.Title>
         </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Body>
            {_.map(modalVariableValues, (variableValue) => {
              return (
                <DropdownVariableRow
                  key={`DropdownVariable${variableValue}`}
                  variableValue={variableValue}
                  modalVariableValues={modalVariableValues}
                  setModalVariableValues={setModalVariableValues}
                  id={`DropdownVariableRow${variableValue}id`}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Update Values</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
     </Modal>
   )    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I lost formating when posting. When I remove the map in the `Modal.Body` and add a word or something then it works. I changed a few things to get an error, like changing the variable names and I did get an error.

Comment: Good to know. Now we isolated the error. I never used lodash before so I'll have to learn something about it to be able to help you. Mind if we do that tomorrow?